# Sum lists of different size Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists with different size: `A= [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]` and `B= [5,6]` I want to sum the two lists `A+B` as :

```
C = A+B =[0.1+5,0.2+5,0.3+6,0.4+6]=[5.1,5.2,6.3,6.4]
```

I tried the following :

1-

```
 C= [sum(n,x) for n, sub in zip(B,A) for x in sub]
```

an error appears:
'float' object is not iterable

2-

```
C=[x + y for x, y in zip(itertools.cycle(B), A)]
```

the result was:

```
C=[5.1,6.2,5.3,6.4]
```

Any suggestion

Comment: So, you're adding `B[n//2]` to `A[n]`? Why not just do that?

Comment: @jarmod can you please give me an example

Comment: Like `C = [A[n]+B[n//2] for n in range(len(A))]`?

Answer (score 3):

```
C=[A[i]+B[i//len(B)] for i in range(len(A))]
```

Comment: You could also double B, [x+y for x,y in zip(A,2*B)].

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read this because I brutally failed in my improve of the solution, so I tried to fix it. But if `B=[1,2,3,4]`, `2*B=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]`, and in that case it won't do what he want's isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
C = [x+y for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(A,B,fillvalue=0)]
```

Edit:
What we are doing here is a list comprehension. It is basically a for loop that puts each item it makes each loop into the list. The built in zip function will stop 'zipping' iterables together when one iterable is exhausted. We use itertools.zip_longest because we do not want to simply lose the numbers in a longer list because we have a shorter list. The fill value is 0 for obvious reasons. So for every iteration in our zip function, we simply add them together. Hope I explained it ok.

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.

Comment: @SherylHohman Sorry I'm pretty new to stack overflow. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Why only keep it in mind for the future, why not also improve this answer?